# rosrun Couldn't find executable named

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

After creating a new package and code in it, I got the one below;

> [rosrun] Couldn't find executable named tf_result below
>   /home/aybakana/catkin_ws/src/pcl_tutorials

I tried all sourcing stuff etc. but it does not work.

Does anyone know why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out that the reason is that I deleted the part below from CMakeLists.txt file.

```
catkin_package( ## if you dont add this, executables are not found
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES pcl_tutorials
  CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs nav_msgs pcl_msgs roscpp rospy std_msgs
  DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this occurred when I made invalid changes to my CMakeLists.txt. Ensure that the app can compile then try running `catkin_make` again.

If not, then try removing your devel and build folders and rebuild your application. Don't forget to source your setup.bash file: `source ./devel/setup.bash` before running your node again.